# Restyle Pinterest Widget?

Tags: jquery, css, widget, pinterest

Is it possible to restyle this standard Pinterest widget? Take a look here. Let's say I simply want to change the background color:

http://business.pinterest.com/widget-builder/#do_embed_user (hit "Preview" to actually see it)

Nothing I do has any effect... amending my stylesheet, or even if I use jQuery and target it with something like `.css('background-color','black')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here's what's going on with the Pinterest widget: every time the page loads, the Pinterest widget script assigns itself a new CSS class name. So targeting it with CSS is tricky because you can't point to it directly. I was able to get to it by following a specific CSS path, like this:

```
div#pinterest_wrapper > span > span:first-child { background-color: black; }
```

where `div#pinterest_wrapper` is a `<div>` that I wrapped the their code in... just so I could find it easier. Once I got the path correct, it was a snap to style as needed.

(It's got a nested `<span>` heirarchy. And as shown above, it's that first internal `<span>` that you'll probably need to apply most styles to.)